# how to allow specifiy incomming ssh users,even after blocking specific hosts?

Tags: ssh, security, hosts

i want to take ssh by one specific user in linux.
also i block all other IP to take ssh except some specific IP.
my `/etc/hosts.allow` file is

```
sshd : localhost : allow
sshd : 192.168.1.23 : allow
sshd : ALL : deny
```

I allow only one IP which have access of my server via ssh, but now I want to connect using ssh by one specific user from anywhere.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

According to  `man sshd_config`

> AllowUsers:
>
> This keyword can be followed by a list of user name patterns, separated by spaces.
>                If specified, login is allowed only for user names that match one of the patterns.
>                Only user names are valid; a numerical user ID is not recognized.  By default, login
>                is allowed for all users.

you must allow of course incomming ssh from any IP. If you keep IP restriction, you will restrict to

1. a specific user
2. and from localhost or 192.168.1.23